# Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE & JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

- We are using `Spring boot 2.1.6` and for test purposes we have added `spring boot starter test 2.1.6`
- `spring boot starter test 2.1.6` comes with `JUnit4`
- We are planning to use `JUnit5`

**Question:**

- How would I know which `spring boot starter test` version using Junit5 will be compatible with `Spring boot 2.1.6`?

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Boot 2.1.x versions are [no longer supported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions). Spring Boot 2.2 and higher uses JUnit 5 by default according to [the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#junit-5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. so it is not recommended to use junit5 with the version 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude JUnit-4 from spring boot starter tester:

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

and use JUnit5 there is no problem with your spring boot version at all.
Remember JUnit 5 use a different package (`org.junit.jupiter`).

Comment: Thanks .. i already did it ..and it seem to be working fine… but is there any matrix from which i can check for compatibilities …